# Excel: Dynamic Named Range - Last Non Text Value

Tags: excel, formulas, named-ranges

I have the following table in my spreadsheet:

```
    A              B   C
1   R1             1   2
2   R2             2   3
3   R3             4   5
4   Grand Total    7   10
5   0              0   0
6   0              0   0
7   0              0   0
```

I'm looking to create 4 dynamic named ranges which will select data in the respective columns up until it finds the text "Grand Total" in column A.

So far, I've used

```
=OFFSET(Analysis!$A$1,0,0,MATCH("*",Analysis!$A:$A,-1),1)
```

which returns A1:A4.

I need it to return A1:A3. I also need named ranges, in this example, to return B1:B3, C1:C3 etc. They need to be dynamic so that when the list expands to past row 6, it continues to search for Grand Total.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using:

```
=INDEX(Analysis!$A:$A,1):INDEX(Analysis!$A:$A,Match("Grand Total", Analysis!$A:$A, 0)-1)
```

The problem with offset is volatility, which means it'll recalculate each time there is an update.

EDIT: Added $ to lock those ranges for reasons...

EDIT2: Changed 2nd index to match due to update from comments.

Comment: Sorry - just clarified my question. In Rows 5 onwards, in this example, the cells all contain 0. Tried your formula but I think it doesn't work with the zeros.

Comment: Try replacing COUNTA()-1 with Match("Grand Total",Analysis!$A:$A,0)-1. The dynamic ranges for B and C would also use Match on the A column.

Comment: You could replace the first `INDEX` function with `$A1` as that's what it always returns: `=$A1:INDEX(Analysis!$A:$A,Match("Grand Total",Analysis!$A:$A,0)-1)`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I tend to prefer the version as originally given by Kevin, if only since, with your version, deleting row 1 will cause errors. Sounds like a touch overkill, but experience has taught me that guarding against unwanted row/column insertions/deletions is more than worth the little extra formula-work required.

Comment: @XORLX - True, I hadn't considered the row being deleted.  I try to guard against that by locking down the spreadsheet, using forms, giving staff electro shock therapy when they do it wrong.... all the usual stuff. :)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I know - you simply can't guard against every eventuality! All you can do is try! :-)